# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when opening Command option for a UI Control

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've been using MVVM in an application I'm building using Visual Studio 2010.
For the UI controls I'm using Commands that are bound to certain controls. Recently I've added some more Commands and when I try to add one to one of the controls Visual Studio crashes.

The crash actually happens when I'm in the visual editor, select a UI control (let's say a button) and try to add Databinding to its Command property.

If I do it through XAML everything works perfectly but I'd like to use the UI.
Is this because of a problem in my code? Or is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have more than one version of visual studio installed? I had a lot of simillar issues after installing VS2k12 on the same box. They share a lot of dlls, and uninstalling 2k12 did not restore the prior images. had to snag them from a colleagues box. anything in the application event log? have you tried a simple test project to see if the issue is your code?

Comment: No, only have VS2010. The problem started happening after adding some more properties in a ViewModel.